Parameter Hints Not Showing for TypeScript Generic Types Imported from Other Files in VS Code
In VS Code + TS Language, I have defined a generic type:
type Generic<T1 extends string = "Hello", T2 extends sting = "World"> = `${T1} ${T2}`;

When I use the type in the same file, the parameter hints popup shows perfectly fine and tells me what the type expects me to pass:
// Generic<T1 extends string = "Hello", T2 extends sting = "World">

However, when I export this type and import it into another file, the parameter hints do not show.
I wanted to include an image (.gif) to make it easy to understand my problem, but StackOverflow said:

You need at least 10 reputation to post images.

